# Updating since jvm time in background

Tags: java, jvm

`long jvmUpTime = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getUptime();`

how to update this in background? 
for example, my application stores in `jvmUpTime` only one value.

there is a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the value to change you can use a method.

```
long jvmUpTime() { return ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getUptime(); }
```

This way the value is checked each time you call it instead of storing a copy.